# casting Python str to C const char *

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, swig

i just started some Python Wrapper for a C .dll. And used SWIG for it. I ran into the problem that a C Function from the dll takes a  typedef of a `const char *` as argument. I Wrapped the .h of my C libary as following (the typedef is copied from the header to the interface when trying a lot of stuff to make it work, don't really know if that is necessary):

```
Added: 
%include "cpointer.i"
%pointer_class(signed char, p_char);

%apply const char * { chararrayiwant }; //not sure if only should be char

Old Code:
%include "typemaps.i"
%include "windows.i"

%module somemodule
%{  #include "someheader.h"
    typedef char chararrayiwant[33];
%}

%include "someheader.h"
typedef char  chararrayiwant[33];
```

When i try to Execute it in my Python file like this:

```
import mylib as d
...
key = b"somereallylongserialkey"  # type: str
p = ctypes.c_char_p(key)
x = d.myfunc(p, 1, None, None)
```

i run into following error:

```
 x = d.myfunc(p, 1, None, None)
TypeError: in method 'myfunc', argument 1 of type 'chararrayiwant const *'
```

I tried this for 2 days now and have not found any solution to make it work..

Thanks in advance!

P.S: does not work with the added lines

Comment: How does myfunc declaraion look like?

Comment: `error_t(typedef int) myfunc(constchararrayiwant *pKeyList, unsigned int numKeys, DeviceEventCallback pDeviceEventCallback = NULL,  void *pUserData = NULL);` @KamilCuk

Comment: What is the type of `constchararrayiwant` ?

Comment: as mentioned in the typedef it should be a `char[ ]`

anyways, i found that i may need add some more information to my `interface file`, edited the above

Comment: thats right, was a typo, sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

I guess You should pass a pointer to string to myfunc not a string. Try:

```
p2 = ctypes.addressof(p);
x = d.myfunc(p2, 1, None, None);
```

The first function argument has the type `constchararrayiwant *` which is `char [33] *` which is `char**`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer about double pointer `char**` could be is a good starting point.

Another thing to consider is to include the SWIG module that allows to work with pointers, and define pointer types that you use, as described here: http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Library.html

Something like this:

```
%include "cpointer.i"

/* Create some functions for working with "char *" */
%pointer_functions(char, char_p);

/* A function that uses a "char *" */
void add(int x, int y, char_p *result);
```

I seems that SWIG does not support work with pointers without this module.